# failed to import project as module - unable to find configuration

Tags: android, gradle

when i'm trying to add project as a module i'm getting this error :

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':sample@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :library.

Could not resolve project :library.
Required by:
    project :sample

> Unable to find a matching configuration of project :library:
>        - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
>            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Apk'.
>            - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>            - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
>        - Configuration 'debugMetadataElements':
>            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Metadata'.
>            - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>            - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' but no value provided.
>        - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
>            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Apk'.
>            - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>            - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found incompatible value 'java-runtime'.
>        - Configuration 'releaseApiElements':
>            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'release'.
>            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Apk'.
>            - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
>            - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
>        - Configuration 'releaseMetadataElements':
>            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'release'.
>            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Metadata'.
>            - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
>            - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' but no value provided.
>        - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':
>            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'release'.
>            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Apk'.
>            - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
>            - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found incompatible value 'java-runtime'.

i researched SO and the only almost working solution i found is to change the line that im adding the project as module to this :

> implementation project(path: ':library', configuration: 'default')

(just adding configuration flag)
than the sync worked but i couldn't import an of the project classes to it didn't help me.